# Autocomplete codes for drupal modules

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I used eclipse IDE for PHP,java.

If i open a php file in eclipse editor,there is a facility of auto completion of the function or keywords.

But i couldn't find any auto complete facilities for "drupal" hooks.Is there any such implementation exists for "drupal" in any IDE?
I am using "drupal-7" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set up a full fledged IDE in PHP (or Drupal) development is very tough job. I use [Sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) editor and it works like a charm.

There is a blog post which is split into two parts for configuring sublime for Drupal:

- [Perfection with Sublime Text - Part 1](http://www.qed42.com/blog/perfection-sublime-text-part-1)
- [Perfection with Sublime Text - Part 2](http://www.qed42.com/blog/perfection-sublime-text-part-2)

Hope this helps!